# Filter a DataGridView without losing unbound changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

Im developing a vb.net application and I have a dgv which displays a list of employees. The dgv has an unbound checkbox column which is used in selecting employees for a required action. I use **rowFilter** to filter the list by department or location or whatever the user chooses.

If the user filters using Department 1 and checks the checkboxes next to the employees he wants, to select them and then filters to Department 2, to select a few more employees, when we filter back to Department 1, the checked employees aren't checked any more.

How can I make it such that once an employee is checked, you can filter with other parameters with losing the earlier selections. Im thinking of saving the checked state of each employee to the database before the next filter but I feel is possibly a quicker easier way. Is there?

This is the code I'm using to fill the dgv

```
 sql = "SELECT employee_paysetup.EmployeeNumber AS EmployeeNo, employee_paysetup.FName, employee_paysetup.MName, " _
                & "employee_paysetup.LName, (case when employee_paysetup.MName = ' ' then concat(employee_paysetup.FName,' ' , employee_paysetup.LName) else " _
                & "concat(employee_paysetup.FName,' ' , employee_paysetup.MName,' ' , employee_paysetup.LName) end) " _
                & "AS FullName, costcenters.CostCenterName AS cosName, departments.DepartmentName AS depName, " _
                & "positions.PositionName AS posName, locations.LocationName AS locName, CostCenter, Department, Position, EmployeeLocation, PayGroup " _
                & "FROM ((((((employee_paysetup LEFT JOIN employees ON employee_paysetup.EmployeeNumber = employees.EmployeeNumber) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN costcenters ON employees.CostCenter = costcenters.CostCenterID) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN departments ON employees.Department = departments.DepartmentID) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN positions ON employees.Position = positions.PositionID) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN locations ON employees.EmployeeLocation = locations.LocationID) " _
                & "LEFT JOIN paygroups ON employee_paysetup.PayGroup = paygroups.ID) " & filterValue
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "ACTIVE")
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        'sort
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "FullName ASC"
        dgvEmployees.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
```

And I filter using

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter  = "myFilter"
```

Comment: Transform the employees to a "view model" and add the selected property so you can bind it.

Comment: Crowcoder could you elaborate a bit more please

Comment: You should [edit] your post to add some code showing what you are doing and how.  We dont know a single detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there us no storage provided for the unbound column.  A fairly simple way of doing this is to use the `DataTable`.  Add a `Selected` column via SQL so that a column is created for it in the `DataTable`:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT False As Selected, Id, Name, Descr, Bird, Color, ItemDate FROM Sample"
```

With most DB providers this will work fine: The table will have a Boolean column and the DGV will add a check column for it.  But there is a slight problem with MySQL since it lacks a way to CAST to `Boolean` or tinyint.  As a result the column will be text.  So, for MySql, skip the SQL Selected column and add a new column to the table:

```
' after the DS is built, but BEFORE it is bound to the DGV:
Dim dc As New DataColumn("Selected", GetType(Boolean))
dc.DefaultValue = False    ' important!
dtSample.Columns.Add(dc)
dc.SetOrdinal(0)           ' make it column 0
```

Be sure to set the `DefaultValue` to something or it will be `DBNull` for all the rows and choke the check column.  It is also important to do this *after* the `DataSource`/`DataTable` is built but *before* you bind it to the DGV.

You can also catch and replace the Text column for a Check column in the `ColumnAdded` event. Either way NET knows it is a "virtual" column, so it will not interfere with any `DBCommand` objects you may have built for the `DataAdapter` (the OP cant have any based on that query, but future readers may).   Results:

[image]

I check-selected several `orange` and `Stork` rows, then filtered and the checks remained.  At the core, this and Mr CrowCoder's answer do the same thing just differently: provide somewhere to store the `Selected` state.  This method uses the DGV's normal ability to automatically save to the `DataTable`.

---

If you want to use the `ColumnAdded` event:

```
If e.Column.Name = "Selected" AndAlso TypeOf e.Column Is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Then
    Dim dc As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    dc.HeaderText = "Selected"
    dc.Name = "Selected"
    dc.DataPropertyName = "Selected"
    dc.ValueType = GetType(Boolean)
    dgv5.Columns.Remove(e.Column)
    dgv5.Columns.Insert(0, dc)
    dc.DisplayIndex = 0
End If
```

The **really important thing** is to assign the `DataPropertyName` so the DGV knows where in the table to store the data.

Directly adding a column to the `DataTable` is simpler and more direct, this can be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have Employee:

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property EmpName As String
    Public Property EmpNumber As Integer
End Class
```

And your winform may have a method to get a list of Employee:

```
Public Function GetEmployees() As List(Of Employee)
        'obviously, actually fill a list...
        Return New List(Of Employee)()
End Function
```

Often the "View" (in your case, the winform), has different needs than the back-end data. So you make an `EmployeeViewModel`:

```
Public Class EmployeeVM
    Public Property EmpName As String
    Public Property EmpNumber As Integer
    Public Property EmpIsSelected As Boolean
End Class
```

So you edit `GetEmployees` to get and transform the employee list into an `EmployeeVM` list, and bind that to the grid. Then you can filter all you want and the `EmpIsSelected` property will persist.

When you `Save`, or whatever, you transform the view model back into `Employee`.

This is a rudimentary MVVM pattern that solves the problem of UI having different data needs than the back end.

Comment: Great. I will try that. Thank you!